# Create new view within Report; use different data. In order to export 2 reports to same page in Excel

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, obiee

I am using Oracle OBIEE 11.1.1.5.0

I have 2 existing views saved as separate reports. One is a Pivot; the other is a Table. Their data sources are unrelated.

I want to be able to combine both views into one compound view within one report, so I can export both to the same Excel file.

Please let me know how to implement. Please excuse my word selection; I am very new to this product.

**Edit**: It was suggested that I include both reports on a dashboard, and then export from there. Here are my available dashboard options. Am I missing an Export option that should be visible for the version I am using? Am I not seeing it because I don't have full permissions?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

long story short, it seems as though OBIEE 11.1.1.5.0 does not give you a seamless way to export entire Dashboard pages to Excel.

HOWEVER, there is an ugly way to do it.

Page Options --> Print --> Printable HTML --> Save As --> .xls

[see this thread for more info.](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2609358)

[here is another thread](http://satyaobieesolutions.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-export-dashboard-reports-for.html).